# extracting user_IDs from a json file

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that contains tweets data from a trending hashtags, now after creating my son file I need to extract only the users screen_name of all users. 
trying using the following code result in error: 
 File "/Users/Adel/Documents/Tweepy/jsonextracting.py", line 19, in 
    my_dict['id']=item.get('id')
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

the python code:

```
import json
input_file=open('/Users/Adel/Downloads/data/test.json', 'r') 
output_file=open('/Users/Adel/Downloads/data/test2.json', 'w') 
json_decode=json.load(input_file)
 for item in json_decode:
 my_dict={}
 my_dict['id']=item.get('id')
 print my_dict
 back_json=json.dumps(my_dict, output_file)
 output_file.write(back_json)
 output_file.close()
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you iterate over a dictionary you are only iterating over the keys try

```
 for item in json_decode.values():
```

which will iterate over the values instead